# Ajax call ever x second and update table

Tags: jquery, ajax, setinterval

I want to make AJAX Get call execute ever 5 seconds and checks the length of the contents. If the length has changed, then it should update the table with the new items, if not keep old records. The problem I have right now is that, the table does update but it re-adds all the items from before with the new one. How do I fix this issue so only the new item is added to the already existing ones in the table?

```
$(function(){
var orderTable = ("#orderTable");
var lastResponse = 0;
var sTemplate;
var tableTemplate = '<tr>\
<th>{{Name}}</th>\
<th>{{Order}}</th>\
<th>{{Price}}</th>\
</tr>'

setInterval(function() {
$.ajax({
type: 'GET',
cache: false,
url: "http://localhost:51834/CoffeeService.svc/getallorders/",
success: function(orders){
  console.log(orders);
  if(lastResponse.toString().length === orders.toString().length)
  {
    console.log("LR" + lastResponse.toString().length);
    console.log("same stuff");
  } else {
    console.log("new stuff");
    lastResponse = orders;
    console.log("LR" + lastResponse.toString().length);
    $.each(orders, function(i, order){

      var sTemplate = tableTemplate;
      sTemplate = sTemplate.replace("{{Name}}", order.Name);
      sTemplate = sTemplate.replace("{{Order}}", order.Order);
      sTemplate = sTemplate.replace("{{Price}}", order.Price + " -kr;");
      $("#orderTable").append(sTemplate);
      });
     }
    }
   });
  }, 1000);
});
```

Comment: I'd suggest against using AJAX polling. It can effectively be DDOSing your own server if you have even a moderate amount of traffic. I'd look in to using websockets instead of you need to keep the client data synchronised with the server.

Answer (score 1):

Wrap the functionality in a function:

```
var tryCall = function () {
    // your AJAX call here, with its callback and all
};
```

And set the function to execute every 5 seconds:

```
setInterval(tryCall, 5000);
```

Currently you're trying to invoke the *result* of only a single call to `$.ajax()`, and trying to do so every 1 second.

Comment: I am having an issue with data being repeatedly added every 1 second to the table now.

Comment: @kennyYice23: Did you change the interval from 1 second to 5 seconds as suggested?  If you're executing the code every second, then it's going to execute every second.

Comment: I did. It keeps on adding the same data and I have not added any new content.

Comment: @kennyYice23: When you debug, what causes this?  What are the actual runtime values being compared in your `if` condition?

Comment: The thing that I am trying to compare is the response from the server. I want the table to add the records once and then continue making the get request every 5 seconds and update the table only when a new item is added. 

Sorry if it is confusing. I am new to this and trying my best to learn.

Comment: I think that `(appliedData != orders)` is not doing the comparison you want it to do...

Comment: @kennyYice23: This is a good opportunity to familiarize yourself with the use of a debugger, which is going to be your most useful tool as a developer.  Using your browser's debugging tools, place a breakpoint on that line of code and when the execution pauses there you can examine the actual runtime values to see if they are what you think they are, as well as execute commands on the browser console to see if other code does what you expect it to do.  Never assume, always debug.

Comment: It seems that my main problem is in the if statement. As @JohnHascall mentioned. It doesn't really check anything.

Comment: @kennyYice23: Well, it checks `if (appliedData != orders)`.  But if it isn't doing what you expect it to do then you're going to have to examine those values in a debugger and see if they are what you expect them to be.  I suspect that `orders` variable contains more than just a simple scalar value and the comparison isn't what you think.  You may need to adjust your logic based on the actual values, but in order to do that you need to know what those values are.

Comment: Well, I cannot seem to figure out how to compare the previous response with the new one and only add the items if the new response has new items.

Comment: @kennyYice23: If you can share what those values *are* then we may be able to help with the logic.  But without that information all anybody here can suggest is that you examine the values for the differences you're looking to indicate if the data is to be appended or not.

Comment: @David I managed to somehow get it to work but I am still struggling with the re-adding of the items. I edited the question :)

Comment: Given the name "getallorders", I'm guessing it returns ALL the orders (including the ones already in your table). So perhaps instead of appending to the table you should completely replace the table contents OR in your "each loop" you need to check if this order is already in the table and skip appending if it is.